# Can we use our own facebook application for wordpress feeds

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

Is there any way to share wordpress feed by our own FB application

for example now we use rss graffity and its posted by "via Rss Graffity"

Can we share our feeds on facebook "via FbStuff.in"

Is There any plugin or any  way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not used this plugin yet and not sure if it will work under the latest WordPress but i've heard of a few people using it. [WordBook for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordbook/). I'm sure theres a few other options.